# Would you play an iphone game cause it gives you money?

Tags: iphone, 2d-games

I have an iphone game that is going to be released in a week. I intended to give the weekly top scorer real money ($100 and it wil increase as the player base increases). Would you play this game even if it wasn't too appealing? i.e, if you are the weekly top scorer you will get paid $100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would I have to pay for the game?
If so, how much?

I believe everyone would want to play your game if you offered a weekly reward for $100.

(PS, sign me up, what's the game's name?)

Comment: its free and it is yet to be released and its so simple and straight forward

Comment: cool then ye u should get quite a large customer base in no time. what's the game like?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I'd rather leave it until it is released. Do you by any chance know if that was legal or not?

Comment: If what was legal or not?

Comment: us giving away money to the top scorer

Comment: Umm no there shouldn't be any legal issue as long as the user agrees to the terms of your game (basically when they first sign up, place some terms and conditions, saying if they are top scorer of the week, they agree to receive (or refuse) a reward of $100)

Answer (score 0):

This is a psychology question not a programming one.